# how to compare two files and print unmatched records

Tags: printing

If record from file1 matches record from file2 the record NOT need to be output to file3.
I have two files:

file1

```
one
one 
two 
three
three 
four 
five
five
five
six
six
```

file2

```
one
three
six
```

output file3 should be

```
two
four
five
```

I tried

```
diff --old-line-format="" --unchanged-line-format="" file1 file2
```

but it didn't return what I need

Thanks,
Ella

Comment: diff matches files, not list items. Seems like the wrong tool for what you want to do.

Comment: Probably you are right. What is the right tool for what I want to do? Thanks

Comment: This seems like something that would be a good introductory exercise for a scripting language like Python. You can do it with bash and friends, but I think it's on the border where it starts being easier to use a proper language. Unless maybe someone knows a couple of commands which happen to be useful for the task.

Answer (score 1):

For a simple one-way difference, you can use grep, ex.

```
$ grep -vxFf file2 file1
two
four
five
```

If you need two-way differences, then a good choice is `comm` - however the files must be lexically ordered:

```
$ comm <(sort file2) <(sort file1)
        five
        four
                one
                six
                three
        two
```

or for just the lines unique to `file1`

```
$ comm -13 <(sort file2) <(sort file1)
five
four
two
```

---

If there are duplicates in `file1` and you wish to exclude them from the output, then you can either use `grep` and pipe the result through `sort -u`, or use `comm` and change the plain sort to `sort -u`:

```
grep -vxFf file2 file1 | sort -u
```

or

```
comm -13 <(sort file2) <(sort -u file1)
```

---

Alternate method using Awk, that de-duplicates and preserves order:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {seen[$0]; next} !($0 in seen){print; seen[$0]}' file2 file1
two
four
five
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but it file1 sometimes has duplicate records: like one
one
two 
three
three
three
four 
five
five
six
six.     
File2 never has duplicate. In this case it doesn't work correctly.

Comment: @EllaLiderman please edit your question to include this information, as well as the desired output for that case

Comment: I edited my question with desired output